# System() function of php not working

Tags: php

```
$output = system('SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\GCC G++ compiler\bin && cd/ && c: && cd xampp\htdocs\College Coding\lessons\HTML && g++ -o temp temp.cpp && temp.exe > output.txt',$ret);
```

temp.cpp is not getting compiled in my machine. I tried on another and it is working.
it is not creating `output.txt`

Comment: Please, briefly explain what you are trying to and aiming.

Comment: i have a c++ file named temp.cpp in HTML folder....i want to compile that code and save the output to output.txt

Comment: this code is working on onother machine but not on mine.

Comment: Check your php.ini, is there any `disable_functions`

Comment: shared host? Then perhaps u don't have permissions to run the program

Comment: Try using exec instead and change `>output.txt` with `2>&1` then var_dump($ret);

Comment: then what to do to get permission.... @DarkBee

Comment: what 2>&1 will do and var_dump($ret) @DarkBee

Comment: `2>$1` Will chain the std_error channel to the std_out channel. Making errors u'd only see in the command line visible. With exec the output is stored in the 2nd var, `$ret` by var dumping this u can see if any errors occured during execution of the command

Comment: $output = exec("SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\GCC G++ compiler\bin && cd/ && c: && cd xampp\htdocs\College Coding\lessons\HTML && g++ -o temp temp.cpp && temp.exe 2>$1", var_dump($result));echo $result;

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\College Coding\lessons\HTML\index.php on line 89
NULL 
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\College Coding\lessons\HTML\index.php on line 90

Comment: what i used and the output? @DarkBee

Comment: $output = '';
exec('SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\GCC G++ compiler\bin && cd/ && c: && cd xampp\htdocs\College Coding\lessons\HTML && g++ -o temp temp.cpp && temp.exe 2>$1',$output);
var_dump($output);

Comment: array(0) { } 
Notice: Use of undefined constant output - assumed 'output' in C:\xampp\htdocs\College Coding\lessons\HTML\index.php on line 92
output

Answer (score 0):

What the output.txt should contain ? Are you trying to get the command output in $output var ?
You can use [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

passthru("your_command", &$output);

Then $output will contain all outputs of your commands

Anas

Comment: output.txt will contain the output of the compiled C++ program (temp.cpp)

Comment: passthru is also not compiling....this code is working on another machine but not on mine.